# TypeError: func() missing 1 required positional argument 'n' leetcode

Tags: python, typeerror

I have this function I grabbed from a LeetCode solution

```
def countAndSay(n):
    """
    :type n: int
    :rtype: str
    """
    s = '1'  # sequence
    for _ in range(1, n):
        c = 1  # count
        ns = ''  # next sequence
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if i > 0 and s[i-1] == s[i]:
                c += 1
            if i > 0 and s[i-1] != s[i]:
                ns += str(c) + s[i-1]
                c = 1
            if i == len(s) - 1:
                ns += str(c) + s[i]
                c = 1
        s = ns
    return s
```

I'm trying to run it in the python interpreter by typing

```
from countandsay import countAndSay
countAndSay(5)
```

But I receive the error message

```
TypeError: countAndSay() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'
```

Why is this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Are you _sure_ that is the code you are running? Did you edit `countandsay` after importing it?

Comment: Same I can't reproduce the ```TypeError``` with the code you have provided.

Comment: Did you by any chance put countAndSay() into a class? This error looks to me like you are calling a class method without initializing an object of this class first. In this case, the argument you pass to the function is interpreted as "self" and the argument that you want to pass to the function ('n' in your case) is "missing".